# CMake project inside a qmake project

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake

Long story short, we have a Qt project that I'm thinking of migrating to CMake. However, some of our customers use the existing library as a subproject in a Qt subdirs project. Does that mean we are stuck with Qt for the build system?

Comment: "in a Qt subdirs project" -> I will make an assumption that you mean qmake. If not, please clarify. I believe, you could work it around, but it would be ugly. Why not support both for the time being, and make the qmake variant obsolete, and give the customers a reasonable amount of time for the switch? Would they accept that approach?

Comment: Yeah, that was my backup option...

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:ConvertFromQmake :)

Comment: Did it answer your concern?

Comment: Not really. QT Creator has support for both CMake and QMake projects. However, using the method below you have no way of being able to link between different projects (other than alot of ugly manual stitching). From what I can tell, you are stuck with one or the other.

Comment: @lpapp new link for the script: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/contrib/scripts/ConvertFromQmake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but ugly. You could for instance use the system() function in a qmake file:

> [system(command[, mode])](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command-mode)
>
> You can use this variant of the system function to obtain stdout from the command and assign it to a variable.
>
> For example:
>
> UNAME = $$system(uname -s)
> contains( UNAME, [lL]inux ):message( This looks like Linux ($$UNAME) to me )

As discussed in the comment, your fallback option would be to maintain both for your project, and give your customer a reasonable amount of notice period for qmake so that they have enough time for the migration if they are willing to.

Otherwise, running the desired cmake and build commands with the system() function looks, at least one, way to go.